# Why are end cities not generated in survival, though in creative they are?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft version is `1.13`. I've created 2 worlds with the same seed: one for creative and one for survival (everybody do like this, i think:) ). In creative world I found some end citites, but when I went to the same place in my survival, the end city wasn't here.

Then I tried the following: I copied folder with survival world, switched to creative in it, found another end city... And when I went to this place in survival here was nothing. Why? I always thought, that the same seeds give exactly the same worlds.

Important note: Of course, I've checked the `Generate structures` option. Few end cities, that I found in creative, generated in survival too. So, at least they can be generated in my survival world at all.
BTW, I noticed exatcly the same issue with shipwrecks.

Comment: There's a bug where some structures don't generate in all chunk generation orders. So when you approach from one side, it generates, but not from the other side or when teleporting. Do you still know the two ways you approached it? We're still looking for a way to reliably reproduce it.

Comment: @FabianRöling, in my creative world (where city's generated) I've used the `/tp` command, while in survival I've built extremely long bridge of cobblestone to achieve this far island.

Comment: Does the same happen when you bridge over from the same direction again? If yes, that's awesome, that would finally be a reliable way to reproduce it.

Comment: Or give yourself some Elytra and Fireworks. Spawning in those items shouldn't affect the way the world spawns - and should help speed things up a bit

Answer (score 2):

End Cities don't strictly follow the seed, they're dependent on rng (random number generator). Similarly to how you get a random amount of diamonds between 1 and 4 with fortune 3, or how when you get a mob spawn somewhere 'random'.
Each end city has a pre determined position to generate along with a probability to generate. The output of RNG will decide if the end city should generate which is done upon loading chunks hence why end cities may not appear even when copying a world and going to the same location in both.
I'd suggest using ADMIST if you want to find end cities and go from location to location until you find one - doing this in creative before hand is a waste of time.